# Disabling spellchecker highlight

Tags: highlight, spell-checking

When activating the spellchecker (with `:set spell spelllang=en_us` for example), all incorrect words are highlighted. I'd prefer if they'd not be highlighted, but the spell checker to continue to work (e.g. pressing `]s` would still take you to the next mistake).

Is there a way to disable only the highlight, without disabling the spellchecker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do `:filter Spell highlight` to see the list of highlight groups related to spell checking. To disable highlighting for a group, for example `SpellBad`, do

```
:highlight clear SpellBad
```